# class contructor with varargs as arguments, store as class attribute and return varargs as function result

Tags: java

I need  to write a class with accepts a  varargs  List of a dedicated  class  type
the class  should store this  list internally as class  attributes  and  return   this  list

my code  , not compiling goes like this

```
public class Sequence implements BasicClassInterface {

   
     private List<BasicClassInterface> befehlsliste  = new ArrayList<>();


    //   copy to a list  is  working 
    public Sequence (BasicClassInterface...  params ) {
    int i;
        for(i=0; i< params .length; i++) {

            befehlsliste.add(  params [i] );
        }           
    }

    //  also fine 
    public void addOneMore (BasicClassInterface  basicClassInterface )  {  befehlsliste.add( basicClassInterface);    }

   //  my problem ...   how to return a vararg of basicClassInterface ??? 
   public Sequence  getSeqence () {   return  befehlsliste.stream().toArray();  ???  }
```

Answer (score 3):

You can't "return varargs". Varargs is just syntactic sugar for arrays and can only be used as parameter types (more specifically, only the *last* parameter of a method/constructor). So, it would seem you want to return an array, which means you need to change your return type to `BasicClassInterface[]` (an array type). You also don't need to use `stream()` to convert a list to an array.

```java
public BasicClassInterface[] getSequence() {
  return befehlsliste.toArray(BasicClassInterface[]::new);
}
```

Comment: I must  return  a Sequence Object   public Sequence  getSeqence () {   return ???  } I should return one  elements  with represent the sequence  of the  other elements

Comment: That doesn't really make sense. But if that's the case, are you looking for `return this;`? Don't see how that makes the method useful, however. Perhaps if you clarified what the `getSequence()` method is supposed to be actually used for?